# Changes to dconf-editor not applied

Tags: suspend, power-management, ubuntu-gnome, dconf

I am running Ubuntu Gnome 16.10. By default it suspends after 5 minutes of inactivity. I want to change this so that the screen will go blank at most, but not that it suspends. I have tried to change this in dconf-editor. But although dconf-editor saves the changes that I have made, they are not applied. I am making these changes to the user account, not root.

Here are the changes I have made. org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power -> sleep-inactive-ac-timeout = 0
sleep-inactive-ac-type = 'nothing'
sleep-inactive-battery-timeout = 0
sleep-inactive-battery-type = 'nothing'

Thanks

[dconf-editor screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IpHM0.png)